Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" when adding record to Access database
I've searched for hours for a solution to this problem but nothing I've read has helped. I'm getting this error when trying to add this record to an Access database.
this is the code:
Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into Table1([FullName]),([agency]),([shelf]),([dt]) values (@FullName),(@agency),(@shelf),(@dt)", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", txt_name.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agency", txt_agen.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shelf", txt_she.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", txt_DT.Text)
   
    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Records Save!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Failed!")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
conn.Close()
loading()
clear()

what the problem can someone help. Im newbie

Add tag for coding language.

What is the error? Also this may help: ExecuteNonQuery() for Insert - but avoid .addwithvalue .

The correct syntax for the INSERT INTO is Insert into table (field1, field2, field3) values (value1, value2, value3) Remove the unneeded parenthesys around the field names as well values. Just leave one at start and end of names and values
